# Error import component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this error when i import my component

Module not found: Can't resolve '../src/components/Menu' in '/Users/userName/Documents/folder/repository/Project/src/pages/Home'

```
src
  components
    Menu
      Menu.css
      Menu.js
  pages
    Home.css
    Home.js
```

**Menu.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Menu.css';

class Menu extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="menu">
        <h1>Je suis un Menu</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Menu;
```

**Home.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Home.css';
import Menu from './../components/Menu';

class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      msg: 'Hello from the state of Home'
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="home">
        <h1 className="text">Welcome to the Home Page</h1>
        <p>{this.state.msg}</p>
        <Menu/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: check your path, some IDE`s as IntelliJ help you with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import from one level deeper:

```
import Menu from './../components/Menu/Menu';
```

You have a folder called `Menu` and the file you want is inside called `Menu.js`.

Comment: this true : import Menu from './../../components/Menu/Menu'; Thank you =)

Answer (score 1):

That's because `'../src/components/Menu'` doesn't point to your file.

Either use the path

```
'../src/components/Menu/Menu'
```

*Or*, if you want to use your original path, rename your `Menu.js` file to `index.js`.

In my experience the latter tends to be more popular due to it's [inclusion in the hugely useful Airbnb JSX style guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/react).